# SSIS SQL Task query adding Cross Join for no reason

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following UPDATE query:

```
    UPDATE    A
    SET       A.EARLY_SHIFT =
        (SELECT     DATEPART(hour, S.SCHED_START - A.FIRST_LOGIN) * 3600 
                  + DATEPART(minute, S.SCHED_START - A.FIRST_LOGIN) * 60 
                  + DATEPART(second, S.SCHED_START - A.FIRST_LOGIN) AS Expr1)
         FROM   DLY_AGT_ACTIVITY AS A
         INNER JOIN  DLY_AGT_SCHEDULES AS S
              ON A.DATE = S.DATE AND RIGHT(A.ID, 5) = RIGHT(S._ID, 5)
```

This in Management studio runs perfectly. However, in my sql task of my SSIS package, it adds a CROSS JOIN like so:

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.EARLY_SHIFT =
      (SELECT  DATEPART(hour, S.SCHED_START - A.FIRST_LOGIN) * 3600 
             + DATEPART(minute, S.SCHED_START - A.FIRST_LOGIN) * 60 
             + DATEPART(second, S.SCHED_START - A.FIRST_LOGIN) AS Expr1)
        FROM DLY_AGT_ACTIVITY AS A 
         INNER JOIN DLY_AGT_SCHEDULES AS S 
             ON A.DATE = S.DATE AND RIGHT(A.ID, 5) = RIGHT(S._ID, 5) CROSS JOIN A
```

And this makes the query fail in my sql task. What the heck is going on?

*I have tried running without any aliases, and this did not help.

Comment: how odd, what happens if you take the cross join off in SSIS?

Comment: It gives an error of Unable to update column EARLY_SHIFT, and adds the cross join again.

Comment: I don't understand why you have parenthesis -- that is, why they end after `Expr1`

Comment: The parenthesis that encapsulates from SELECT to Expr1? Removing these throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restructured your update query, but it should give the same result.

```
UPDATE DLY_AGT_ACTIVITY
SET EARLY_SHIFT = DATEPART(hour, S.SCHED_START - FIRST_LOGIN) * 3600 
    + DATEPART(minute, S.SCHED_START - FIRST_LOGIN)                                                
    * 60 + DATEPART(second, S.SCHED_START - FIRST_LOGIN) 
FROM         DLY_AGT_SCHEDULES AS S 
WHERE   DLY_AGT_ACTIVITY.[DATE] = S.DATE 
AND     RIGHT(ID, 5) = RIGHT(S._ID, 5)
```

Can you try this in your package and let me know if it resolves the SSIS issue?

Comment: Yes, this does resolve it, thank you! Do you have any idea why the error is there in the first place?

Comment: I think it's a known Microsoft bug similar to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953119.  I think you can avoid the issue by not needing to restate the table name in the select statement